# Strange result with Mathematica

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I am trying to integrate the following using Mathematica:

```
Integrate[Exp[a*Cos[theta]], {theta, 0, 2*Pi}]
```

I get 2 $\pi$ BesselI[0, a] (which is correct).

Next, I try

```
Integrate[Exp[a*Cos[2*theta]], {theta, 0, 2*Pi}]
```

which also gives me 2 $\pi$ BesselI[0, a].

But should the integral not be twice the previous amount?

Comment: I think you are wrong and Mathematica is right.  You could try substituting a numerical value for `a` and changing the `Integrate` to `NIntegrate`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The results seems correct. As the frequency of oscillation increases, there are more waves, but the area under each one decreases also, keeping the overall area the same. Just plot it and you will see. Here is example using $a=2$ (pick any other value you want)

```
Table[Integrate[Exp[a*Cos[n*theta]], {theta, 0, 2*Pi}], {n, 1, 6}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Compare to

```
Table[Plot[Exp[2*Cos[n*theta]], {theta, 0, 2*Pi}], {n, 1, 6}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Visually, you can see the total area being the same seems reasonable. There are more segments, yes, but each is smaller.

Ok, this is not a mathematical proof, but at least you can see the result seems correct.  The problem is that Mathematica can not find the indefinite integration. Only definite one.

The result also confirmed by numerical integration

```
 Table[NIntegrate[Exp[2*Cos[n*theta]], {theta, 0, 2*Pi}], {n, 1, 6}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]